# Prevent echo in ant input task

Tags: ant

How do you prevent ant's input task from echoing/printing in the console?

When requesting input in ant, it echoes the characters as you type.  This isn't ideal for password inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution.

As of Ant 1.7.1, this can be done by setting the handler to SecureInputHandler, see code below:

```
<input
    message="    [input] password(Appserver):${line.separator}"
    addproperty="password">
    <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
</input>
```

Strangely, when you set the handler to org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler, it doesn't display as it does with other input in that:

1. It doesn't have "    [input]" prepended
2. Doesn't move the cursor to the next line
   As such, I have achieved these 2 by modifying the message, see above.